# Does proliferation of Metadata affect my Orgs performance?

Tags: apex, metadata, performance

I've recently installed a fairly large managed package in our Developer org (i.e. in terms of # of apex classes, vf pages etc.). I have since noticed a degradation in performance for Metadata actions. As an example, creating a new or editing an existing Visualforce page can sometimes timeout, Save actions for Classes, Pages etc. take much longer than they used to.

On the face of it, it appears that installing this package has slowed down Metadata actions. So, I have a couple of questions:

- Will it have an impact on Data actions?
- Any ideas why it slows down for Metadata?
- If it is the case that it has slowed Metadata actions down, are there any best practices for minimising the impact when developing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you certain that the performance degradation is due to  this package that you've installed, and not just something like a network hiccup? Responsiveness also depends on the demand being placed on your pod (na6, eu4, etc...) at a given time.

Comment: It's difficult to say conclusively. However, no managed package = good performance, managed package installed = poor performance. I will perform some tests by removing and re-installing the package and observing the differences and update the question with the results.

Comment: You could also check https://status.salesforce.com/status (if you haven't already) to see if there was a disruption around the time that you installed this package.